# Using C++ execution header in R package

Tags: r, rcpp, cran, rcpparmadillo

I am developing an R package containing C++ code, and I would like to use the [standard library header "execution"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/execution). As C++17 is the default on CRAN now, this seems to be fine. However, this header is not yet implemented in Apple Clang, and from what I can tell from the [R for macOS Developer](https://mac.r-project.org/) website, C++ code in R packages on macOS will be compiled using Apple's toolchain.

Hence, my question is: Let's say I have a function similar to the one below, computing the set difference in parallel. Would this cause the package build to fail for macOS on CRAN?

```cpp
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <execution>
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec setdiff(const vec& x, const vec& y) {
  vec xs = sort(x);
  vec ys = sort(y);

  std::vector<double> diff;
  std::set_difference(
    std::execution::par,
    xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), ys.end(),
    std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));

  return conv_to<vec>::from(diff);
}

/*** R
setdiff(1:10, 3)
*/
```

On my own M1 Mac, I can make this compile by adding the following lines to `~/.R/Makevars`, thus making sure I use g++ and not Apply clang.

```
CXX=/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13
CXX17=/opt/homebrew/bin/g++-13
```

Comment: is this something you can check using `rhub::check_for_cran()` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are having an issue *with a particular compiler and implementation of C++17* which is different from having an issue with C++17 'per se'.

*Writing R Extensions* is IIRC pretty clear about 'as provided by the compiler'.  In this case, the C++17 feature you desire is offered by recent `g++` version (including on macOS) but *not* on the (prescribed by the CRAN macOS maintainer) `clang++` version you are faced with on macOS.

There is no path for you to use this on macOS at CRAN until the toolchain updates.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something similar to what @SymbolixAU suggested in a comment.

I created a package named `anRpackage` with the following files:

- `DESCRIPTION`

```
Package: anRpackage
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 1.0
Date: 2024-01-09
Author: Who wrote it
Maintainer: Who to complain to <oystein.sorensen.1985@gmail.com>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line). One more 
  sentence.
License: GPL-3
Imports: Rcpp
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
Encoding: UTF-8
```

- `src/setdiff.cpp`

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
#include <execution>
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec setdiff_par(const arma::vec& x, const arma::vec& y) {
  vec xs = sort(x);
  vec ys = sort(y);
  
  std::vector<double> diff;
  std::set_difference(
    std::execution::par,
    xs.begin(), xs.end(), ys.begin(), ys.end(),
    std::inserter(diff, diff.begin()));
  
  return conv_to<vec>::from(diff);
}
```

- `src/Makevars` and `src/Makevars.win`

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

- An `R` directory containing the auto-generated `RcppExports.R`.

Submitting to win-builder, `devtools::check_win_devel()`, it succeeded. Instead submitting to [R Mac Builder](https://mac.r-project.org/macbuilder/submit.html), the build failed.